# How to edit the user details stored in aspnetdb without asp.net web administration tool?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, membership-provider, aspnetdb

I have asp.net MVC application which uses asp.net membership. I configured the user details from local system using Asp.Net web site administration tool. Now I have deployed the site in server and I need to change the password. Now I have the ASPNETDB.MDF file in the App_Data folder.

How to edit the details?

Answer (score 1):

You could do one of a couple of things.  You can copy the MDF from the site to the local machine, and then change the details there, then copy the MDF back over, or you can implement a web page that changes the password using the [SqlMembershipProvider.ChangePassword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.sqlmembershipprovider.changepassword(VS.85).aspx) method.

Answer (score 1):

Adding [ASP.Net MVC Membership Starter Kit](http://mvcmembership.codeplex.com/) to your project is a great place to start, if you see ongoing edits being required.

Comment: I know this is a year and a half old, but this helped me greatly.

Answer (score 0):

You must call the method MembershipProvider.ChangePassword. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipprovider.changepassword.aspx.